# xenserver 6.5/centos 5.10 parted/glibc upgrade missing dependency that is not missing

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, glibc

I cannot seem to find the official best way to get round this issue:

```
$ yum --enablerepo=base --disablerepo=citrix install parted
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.hyve.com
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package parted.i386 0:1.8.1-30.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol.so.1 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libdevmapper.so.1.02 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libuuid.so.1 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux.so.1 for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libdevmapper.so.1.02(Base) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) for package: parted
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.5 for package: parted
---> Package parted.x86_64 0:1.8.1-30.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper.i386 0:1.02.67-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: e2fsprogs-libs = 1.39-36.xs1393 for package: e2fsprogs
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.i386 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.x86_64 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.5-123 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-123 for package: glibc
---> Package libselinux.i386 0:1.33.4-5.7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libsepol.i386 0:1.15.2-3.el5 set to be updated
---> Package ncurses.i386 0:5.5-24.20060715 set to be updated
---> Package readline.i386 0:5.1-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package e2fsprogs.x86_64 0:1.39-37.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.5-123 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-123 for package: glibc
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
glibc-2.5-123.i686 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-123 is needed by package glibc-2.5-123.i686 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-123 is needed by package glibc-2.5-123.i686 (base)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

but

```
$ rpm -qi glibc
Name        : glibc                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.5                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 123.el5_11.1                  Build Date: Tue 27 Jan 2015 17:35:22 GMT
Install Date: Sun 26 Jul 2015 20:57:15 BST      Build Host: builder17.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: glibc-2.5-123.el5_11.1.src.rpm
Size        : 11690192                         License: LGPL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Tue 27 Jan 2015 22:58:46 GMT, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
Summary     : The GNU libc libraries.
Description :
The glibc package contains standard libraries which are used by
multiple programs on the system. In order to save disk space and
memory, as well as to make upgrading easier, common system code is
kept in one place and shared between programs. This particular package
contains the most important sets of shared libraries: the standard C
library and the standard math library. Without these two libraries, a
Linux system will not function.
```

and

```
$ rpm -qi glibc-common
Name        : glibc-common                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.5                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 123.el5_11.1                  Build Date: Tue 27 Jan 2015 17:35:22 GMT
Install Date: Sun 26 Jul 2015 20:57:22 BST      Build Host: builder17.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: glibc-2.5-123.el5_11.1.src.rpm
Size        : 66738287                         License: LGPL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Tue 27 Jan 2015 22:58:46 GMT, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
Summary     : Common binaries and locale data for glibc
Description :
The glibc-common package includes common binaries for the GNU libc
libraries, as well as national language (locale) support.
```

EDIT:
Now I've seen this:

```
$ yum --enablerepo=base --disablerepo=citrix --showduplicates list glibc-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.hyve.com
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Installed Packages
glibc-common.x86_64                                            2.5-123.el5_11.1                                             installed
Available Packages
glibc-common.x86_64                                            2.5-123                                                      base
```

but don't know how (safe it is) to swp in the base version.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: You are trying to install glibc-2.5-123.i686 while you have installed glibc-common.x86_64 (notice the architecture).

Comment: When I usually use yum, it resolves the architecture for my platform automatically.  If I have the x86_64 version of glibc-common, why is yum now fishing out the x86_64 version of parted?

Comment: Yum in EL5 is very old and kind get a little stupid with multi-arch stuff.  EL5 only has about a year of support left anyways, you really need to move to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me and it's annoying. But here is the workaround. Say _.x86_64 explicitly.

```
yum --enablerepo=base install parted.x86_64
```